# Derivative of integral, which way?

Tags: calculus, integration

I know ${\Large\int} _{x}^{\sqrt x} \ dt$

can be written as $\sqrt{x} - x$

but what is the derivative of ${\Large\int} _{x}^{\sqrt x} \ dt$?

is it 1 or derivative of $\sqrt{x} - x$?

Answer (score 2):

Second answer: derivative of $\sqrt{x}-x$ which is $-1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 2):

It depends on with respect to which variable you're differentiating. If you're differentiating with respect to the variable $x$, then the answer is going to be $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-1$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{x}^{\sqrt x}\,dt\right)=
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x}-x\right)=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-1.
$$

If you're differentiating with respect to the variable $t$, then you would get $0$ because $\sqrt{x}-x$ is a constant (it's like $\sqrt{4}-4$ which is just a number) and the derivative of a constant, as you probably know, is $0$:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{x}^{\sqrt x}\,dt\right)=
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sqrt{x}-x\right)=
0.
$$

Comment: What is your $t$ that you are taking a derivative of? Note the variable $t$ in the integral $\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}} dt$ is just a "dummy" variable as the indication of what is to be integrated, so it doesn't have any relevance outside of the integral, and with it not showing in the final result. As such, you will always get a result of $0$ for any such derivative, not just this particular example. If I'm missing something simple & obvious, I apologize and would appreciate it if you could explain. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether there is a $t$ in the expression or not. You still can differentiate with respect to anything you want. I hope I'm not doing anything wrong, am I?

Comment: In that case, why not also differentiate wrt $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, ..., with all being as valid as using $t$? You are correct $t$ doesn't need to be in the expression, but the variable should have a particular meaning. In this case, as $t$ is not defined as being anything specific, then you need to define what you mean by $t$ to make differentiating wrt to it have any meaning.

Comment: Well, in the OP's example there are two variables $x$ and $t$. In my answer, I show that you get different answers depending on with respect to which of the two variables you're differentiating. That's really all there is to it. I don't know why it rubs you the wrong way.

Comment: Note that $t$ **only** exists and makes sense within the integral. It's a *dummy* variable. It has no particular meaning, and doesn't make sense to reference it outside of that integral, such as in an integration.

Comment: The point was that you get two different answers. He asked what would the derivative of that expression be and did not told us with respect to which of the two variables the integral was supposed to be differentiated. There seems to be two variables there: $x$ and $t$ ($f(t)=1$ is still a function of the variable $t$). If the expression under the integral sign had a $t$ in it, then there would probably be a $t$ in the answer.

Comment: This will be my final comment, so anything we still don't agree on we'll just have to agree to disagree. Your last sentence says "If the expression under the integral sign had a $t$ in it, then there would probably be a $t$ in the answer". This is *not* correct. A simple example is that $\int_{x}^{\sqrt{x}} tdt = \frac{x - x^2}{2}$. My point is that *anything* with $t$ would be integrated, so there will never be any $t$ in the final answer. Also, I will repeat again, what is $t$ supposed to be outside of the integral, as you can't reasonably differentiate wrt a variable if it has no meaning!

Comment: Oh, yeah, it was wrong of me to say that. Anyway, the point was that depending on with respect to which of the two variables you're differentiating, you get different answers regardless of the fact that *t* does not have meaning outside the integral sign (it just dissappears) (I was not even thinking about that. It was irrelevant to my point). Anyway, I appreciate your comments. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with J.O.: to even mention the idea of differentiating this expression with respect to "the variable $t$" is actively misleading. The actual variable $x$ and the dummy variable $t$ are not on the same footing, and it makes no mathematical sense to treat them as similar, nor even to call them "the two variables" in the expression. Side comment: I suggest avoiding assigning a gender to an anonymous person. Assuming the OP must be "he" reinforces our implicit biases against women in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

The generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus says that:

($\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}\  f(t) dt))'= f(h(x))*h'(x)-f(g(x))*g'(x)$

(This is because of the derivative chain rule).
It's pretty easy to go on from here.
Good luck.

Comment: I believe you forgot to add an indication you are taking the derivative of the integral, not just evaluating the integral.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Latex is a new thing to me, writing the integral itself was a tough job!